# Is it possible to bind an event listener to an element within a shadow dom from external script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, content-script, shadow-dom

I have a chrome extension that injects a shadow dom element to a page to keep the css separate. But I need to bind an onclick to some elements within the shadow dom from a content script because I need to be able to invoke functions in the content script by clicking on the elements that are in the shadow dom.

I have tried using the .bind('click', function(){}) on both the elements in the template element and the actual shadow dom element but I can't seem to access them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try querying against the element's shadowRoot. In other words, lets say you have an element `<super-ultra-element>`, and inside that element's shadow dom is a div with class 'potato' that you wish to attach a click handler to.

You should be able to do this by first obtaining the element's shadowRoot: `var superUltraRoot = document.querySelector('super-ultra-element').shadowRoot;`.

Once you have the shadowRoot, you can query the element's shadow dom for the item you care about: `var potatoDiv = superUltraRoot.querySelector('.potato');`.

You now have a reference to the element you're trying to add a click handler to, so doing so should be fairly easy: `potatoDiv.addEventListener('click', someClickCallback);`

Comment: Although I had to use querySelectorAll, this was definitely the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using the .bind('click', function(){}) on both the
>   elements in the template element

1. Adding event listener to template won't work. The element you are binding to should be part of DOM.

> and the actual shadow dom element but I can't seem to access them

2. I don't think jquery understands shadow-root yet. If you are using jquery to query for elements in shadow-dom I don't think it will return a node(Should it?)

So, you have 2 options:

1. As suggested in other answer, you can bind eventlistener to actual element by querying for it inside shadow-root, which can by accessed by shadowRoot property on element.
2. Or, you can use jquery [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind event listener on parent(in this case **host** of shadow-dom) with appropriate selector. When event will be propagated to parent, listener will be fired.

Ex:

```
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using alternative way with Jquery `find` and `on` function, try my snippet here.

```js
$("#CreateShadowRoot").on('click', function (event) {
    const shadowDiv = document.getElementById('ShadowDiv');
    const shadowRoot = shadowDiv.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    const jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
    jQueryScript.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'; 
    shadowRoot.appendChild(jQueryScript);
    shadowRoot.innerHTML += '<button id="example-action">Im inside ShadowRoot</button>';
    function initShadowDOM() {
      // Get the Shadow DOM root element
      // Attach a click event listener using jQuery
      $(shadowRoot).find("#example-action").on('click', function (event) {
        // Handle the click event within the Shadow DOM
        // You can access the event object and perform actions here
        console.log('Event received');
      });
    }
    jQueryScript.onload = function () {
      // jQuery is now loaded and ready to use
      // You can use jQuery event listeners like .on() here
      initShadowDOM(); // Call a function to set up the Shadow DOM content and event listeners
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="CreateShadowRoot">Create ShadowRoot</button>
<div id="ShadowDiv"></div>
```